# jQuery UI Switch Class Animation not animating in Safari / Chrome - but animates in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/b22Yt/1/

I'm trying to do a basic animation for absolute div positioning inside a box when div is hovered.

When div is hovered, div.inside should animate from top to bottom. Using classes. The insider box is dynamic hence why I've had to use the UI way.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/b22Yt/1/) to test what happens. In firefox, its animates. In safari and chrome, it does not? Weird, I have not tested IE yet as I'm on mac.

I got the switch class src from here http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/

Have I done something wrong in my code? even in firefox theres a little jumpiness going on.

Any pro help would be sweet thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/b22Yt/1/

**Markup**

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="inside bottom">

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nisi purus, tincidunt sit amet aliquet quis, semper vel urna. Morbi mollis nulla nisi, ut euismod elit. Nam et arcu velit, id faucibus velit. Sed blandit feugiat quam, nec laoreet nisl suscipit quis.

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.inside {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}


.top {
    top: 0;
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(".box").hover(function(){

     $(this).children(".inside").switchClass( "bottom", "top", 300 );

 }, function() {

     $(this).children(".inside").switchClass( "top", "bottom", 300 );

});
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the UI switchClass method for animating you should always use the same css selectors in both classes, as jQuery UI will need something to compare with.

In other words if the classes look like:

```
.top {top: 0;}
.bottom {top: 200px;}
```

the animation will work just fine cross browser, but if the classes look like:

```
.top {top: 0;}
.bottom {bottom: 0;}
```

jQuery will have trouble comparing those two values and creating an animation between them.
Try it out and you will see.

For your specific example you don't really need jQuery UI at all, and it seems like a strange way to do something basic like animating an element up/down.

I would do it this way instead:

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        child = self.children('.inside'),
        _top = parseInt(self.css('height')) - parseInt(child.css('height')) - 20; //  -20 for padding
        child.css({top: _top});
        $(this).data('_top', _top);
});

$(".box").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".inside").stop(true, true).animate({top: 0}, 300);
 }, function() {
    $(this).children(".inside").stop(true, true).animate({top: $(this).data('_top')}, 300);
});
```

No need for classes or anything else, straight forward, here's a fiddle to show it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/b22Yt/4/

Comment: Hey dude, thanks very much for your reply.
Its nice but when I put in on my site, the height reading it's getting is incorrect and positions it wrong. I've had exactly the same problem with this version http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/14/, this version gets the height of the text div, puts the height into a variable, and then that variable goes into a position. But its wrong on document load. Its fine on this jsFiddle, on all browsers. But when I put this code on my site it gets the incorrect height of the text, but when I hover once, it returns to the correct value.

Comment: It actually seems to be working fine here in Chrome. Looked really fast at your site, looks good, but trying to figure out where everything is on a WordPress site is'nt easy. The function iterates over all the .box elements, getting the height, and then calculating the distance the .inside div should be from the top, storing that distance in the data key and applying it later to get the element down to the right distance after animating up to top:0. It could be something really simple, like using height() instead of using the actual css height, though they should be the same, I have no idea ?

Comment: Ahh, now I see what you mean. The data function actually stores a different value for each element that it iterates over, using a global variable will not work, it will just overwrite the variable on each iteration over all the elements with the class "box", and you end up with the same distance as the last box on all the boxes, you need a different distance for each element, so using the data function is the right way to do this, and it can't be done with just one global variable. It could be done with dot notation, or an array, but data() is much easier, and better.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm not massively up on my jquery/javascript as you can probably tell - but are you saying that instead of a function that runs all the animations globally, using a variable that is different for each one inside that function, wont work?? But I've tested the above jsFiddle in all browsers and it works sweet - is that because it's inline html as opposed to text loaded in by wordpress php?? I'm baffled and that's why I was looking for method that didn't involve a height, hence the top and bottom class position question; which like you said, will never work :/

Comment: If the fiddle works the way you intended it to, and for some reason the same script does not work on your WordPress site, something is interfering, and it probably has nothing to do with the global variables or PHP, none of those should have any importance. It's probably something with the height values returned, and you could try logging those to the console to check that they are returning correctly, if they do, something is overriding the positions set in that script, what or how I have no idea, and you will have to do some fault finding to try and figure it out. The console is your friend.

Comment: Hmmm - cool man, thanks for your advice. Will have to dig deep to work this out, I'm sure there be some logical explanation, tho it might drive me nuts till I find it.

Comment: Worth noting that there appear to be some issues in Chrome with !important also breaking the css properties map and causing elements to snap rather than animate.

Comment: This is such intuitive advice but none the less something I completely looked over. Once I added the properties that would not animate to both classes, worked a charm. This should be listed in the documentation somewhere.